# I can´t override border property of reset.css

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML and a reset.css and base.css. When trying to override "border" property in base.css, it doesn't work and I can't find why.

**HTML**

```
<link href="assets/css/base/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/base/base.css">

<form action="#">
    <fieldset class="login__form">
        <legend>Iniciar Sesión</legend>

        <input class="no-focus border--style" type="text" placeholder="Escriba su correo electrónico" title="Ingrese su e-mail" required>
        <input class="no-focus border--style" type="text" placeholder="Escriba su contraseña" title="Ingrese su contraseña" required>

        <button class="login__button button" type="submit">Entrar</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**reset.css**

```
[tags...], input[type="text" i] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

**base.css**

```
.border--style {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color-grey);
}
```

So, "border-radius" works fine, but "border-bottom" doesn't! The "border: 0;" of reset.css has more power...

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: It would improve your question if you could edit it and use the snippet tool `<>` to load your css, html and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code you have posted everything looks fine.
Maybe try with *!important*

```
    border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem. I heard so many times to avoid using !important, that I forget about that posibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing inline css. Sometimes its better to avoid using !important property to prevent conflicts in files.

Comment: Yes, that also works. But you say is it better to use inline css than _!important_? Thanks

Comment: Yes, its better if you prefer to use inline css than using !important.